# How to apply a function to a list using recursion

Tags: python

How do I apply a function like square(x) to a list like [1,2,3] using recursion? I want to get the result [1,4,9] without using the built-in map function. 
I wrote something like this, but this results in error that never ends.How can I change this?

```
lst=[1,2,3]

def f(x):                                                                          

    return x**2

def map(lst,f):

    i=0
    if i>len(lst):
        return 0
    else:
        lst[i]=f(lst[i])
        i+=1
        return map(lst,f)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: You don't need to use recursion to implement `map`. Most questions like "how do I use recursion to do [thing]?" end up with very awkward solutions, because recursion is not a one-size-fits-all tool. It's great for iterating trees or expressing recurrence relations, but not so much for replacing a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
def f(x):
    return x ** 2

def recursive_map(values, f):
    if not values:
        return []
    else:
        # Here we concatenate the f(head) + tail together:
        return [f(values[0])] + recursive_map(values[1:], f)

values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
result = recursive_map(values, f)
print(result)
```

> `[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]`

Not sure if that helps you to understand a bit how to write a recursive function. Just remember that you always start with the "end" clause, in this case returning the empty list `[]` when our input is empty.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had something similar, but i made other mistakes.